# what is difference between policy and kernelCachePolicy

Tags: caching, iis, web-config

Using IIS 7, I have set output caching which results to this code:

```
  <profiles>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
    </profiles>
```

What is the difference and exact meaning of **policy** and **kernelCachePolicy** and what should I consider when setting these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first understand [IIS architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture),

[image]

To control caching in `http.sys`, use `kernelCachePolicy`. To control caching in `w3wp.exe`, use `policy`.

The pros and cons are also clear based on the architecture diagram.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a related question here. You may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567424/web-config-cache-settings-not-working